# how to make a field unique based on another filed in django models?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to make a field unique based on another field in the same model, this is my model:

```py
    class Shop(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Product(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        shop = models.ForignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want the product's name to be unique only based on Shop, for example, if we have the product `a` from shop `a`, shop `a` can not make another product with the name `a` but shop `b` can make a product with name `a`.
for example we have `name = models.CharField(unique_for_date=date_field)` in models, which make the name unique for the date at `date_field`.
is there anything like `unique_for_date`?
can I handle this operation in models or I should try to handle it in view or form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `Product` table:

```py
class Product(...):
    ...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shop', 'name')
```

This will ensure `Products` must have a unique name across the `Shop` they are related to.